# Do electromagnetic beams interference to each other when they meet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's asume a practical case, we have four 5ghz directional wifi antenas and there is a connection between two of them. If I place the other two and make a connection that the beam goes and meets (or crashes?) to the other beam (from practical let's asume in a center point, distance from of 1km).

Will that crash have any noticeable impact on Tx/Rx ratings?  Of course beams are perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

The crash would not have any effect on the Tx/Rx rating.

The two beams will interfere only at their intersection, but will have no effect 
on each other before or after the intersection.

This is due to the principle of superposition of the EM waves in a linear medium which, for this case, could be re-stated as follows:  the EM field at the receiver will be a sum of the effects of the the two beams if they acted alone.

Since the interfering beam would not have any effect at the receiver of the first beam if it was acting alone, it should not have any effect when both beams are present.

Of course, if this was not the case, wireless broadcasting or communication would not work.

Comment: This mit video is instructive, showing interference of two laser beams  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU